# Can I cancel a resize operation in GParted without causing data loss?

Tags: gparted

I'm currently waiting for GParted to finish resizing a partition, but the progress bar is currently at 0, and it's been taking much longer than usual (perhaps an hour). Is it safe to cancel the resize operation? I don't want to wait days for the resize operation to complete, but I don't want to lose all of my files either. (Is there any way that I can simply pause the resize operation, attempt to recover files, and then resume the resize operation?) **(An update: the operation has finally completed, and my files are still intact!)**

Comment: Gparted is displaying the message "0 of 1 operations completed", and the progress bar is at 0. I'm also running GParted from a live USB.

Comment: Is the drive active (noisy / light) any command line/ debug output? How big is the partition?

Comment: @KarthikT I'm resizing the partition from 186.91 to 127.10 GiB. The flash drive's light is blinking.

Comment: gparted should let you go deeper in the message right? as in it should be expandable to see more detailed progress

Comment: by drive active i meant the drive getting resized

Comment: At the bottom of the window, I see the message resize2fs... (followed by more letters). It can't be expanded for some reason - I have no idea why.

Comment: @KarthikT The resize operation has finished - my files are safe now. :)